# How to fix the following: ''can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'''?

Tags: numpy

I have the following types of x and y values. However, I have around a 1000 sample values, so mentioned only a few here. At line 4, I am getting the following error: ''can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
What am I doing wrong here? The code worked fine for other set of data.
Thanks.

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as poly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1552.55,1552.552,1552.554,1552.556,1552.558,1552.56,1552.562,1552.564]
y= [9.47804E-07,9.62422E-07,9.73348E-07,9.8708E-07,1.00317E-06,1.01292E-06,1.02842E- 
   06,1.04378E-06]
test1 = poly.fit(x1_trimmed, y1_trimmed_norm, no_of_coef)
plt.plot(x1_trimmed, test1(x1_trimmed),linewidth=5)
```

Comment: `sequence` means something like a list (or string).  'multiply' for that is defined as 'repeat', and obviously only works for integer values.  Do you mean to do `array` multiply?  It so, use an array instead of a list!

Answer (score 0):

just convert it to an array.

```
x= np.array(x)
```